# Show div on radiobutton hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Now I have smth like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/54tsowq7/107/

I want to save function if radiobutton selected - div with picture is shown.

But how can I make that when radiobutton text is on hover, the same picture is shown? And when mouseleave - it dissapear?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
        $('.text, .img').hide();
        var $pic = $('#'+$(this).data('picid'));
        var $text = $('#'+$(this).data('textid'));   
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $pic.show();
            $text.show();
        }else{  
            $pic.hide();
            $text.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="img" id="pic2" style='display:none'><img src="http://images.math.cnrs.fr/IMG/png/section8-image.png" alt=""></div>
<div class="img" id="pic3" style='display:none'><img src="http://www.simpleimageresizer.com/static/images/simple-image-resizer-128x128.png" alt=""></div>

<form class="radiobuttons">
  <p class="descr" id="desc1" data-picid="pic2" data-descid="desc1"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item1" value="1" data-picid="pic2" data-textid="text1">Text 1</p>
  <p class="descr" id="desc2" data-picid="pic2" data-descid="desc2"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item2" value="1" data-picid="pic2" data-textid="text2">Text 2</p>
  <p class="descr" id="desc3" data-picid="pic3" data-descid="desc3"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item3" value="1" data-picid="pic3" data-textid="text3">Text 3</p>
</form>

<div class="text" id="text1" style='display:none'>Lorem Ipsum Text1</div>
<div class="text" id="text2" style='display:none'>Lorem Ipsum Text2</div>
<div class="text" id="text3" style='display:none'>Lorem Ipsum Text3</div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit messy, but if I correctly understand, you want something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {


 $('input[type="radio"]').hover(
    function() {
    var $pic = $('#'+$(this).data('picid'));
    var $text = $('#'+$(this).data('textid'));
    if(!$(this).prop('checked')) {
      $pic.show();
      $text.show();
        }
    }, function() {
    var $pic = $('#'+$(this).data('picid'));
    var $text = $('#'+$(this).data('textid'));
     if(!$(this).prop('checked')) {
        $pic.hide();
       $text.hide();;
        }

    }
        );

   $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
   $('.text, .img').hide();
    var $pic = $('#'+$(this).data('picid'));
    var $text = $('#'+$(this).data('textid'));

    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
     $pic.show();
     $text.show();
   }else{  
     $pic.hide();
     $text.hide();
   }
});

});
```

And put your div images to the bottom of your HTML

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your help! I've made some changes that images appear on hover radiobutton text. Its ok with hover, but when a radiobutton selected, the image dissapear : http://jsfiddle.net/54tsowq7/157/ Could you help me with this issue?

Comment: @Anton Только у тебя там два `pic2` добавь первому `<p>` `pic1` вместо `pic2`, а то не правильно будет отображаться

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все работает как надо, только один нюанс - сейчас картинки по ховеру отображаются при наведении на сам "кружочек" радиокнопки. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы ховер срабатывал при наведении на текст рядом с радиокнопкой? Я пробовал менять $('.descr input').hover( на $('.descr').hover(, но тогда картинка снова пропадает при selected радиокнопке. Заранее прошу прощение за свою немощность в этом вопросе)

Comment: да, все так. но почему-то работает с первой кнопкой, при выборе двух остальных - картинки пропадают(

Comment: @KaizakiAgata Гениально! Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `mouseenter` and `mouseout` events.
But this function will not trigger `change` event, `change` event can only trigger when you click on radio button and its attribute or value get changed

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('mouseenter',function() {
   // do anything on mouse hover
});
$('input[type="radio"]').on('mouseout',function() {
   // do anything on mouse leave
});
```

Comment: I give a try, but it doesn't work well, unfortunatelly: http://jsfiddle.net/54tsowq7/129/

Comment: Yeah it because of structure I guess, 1st `mouseenter` event get trigger as it trigger images pops up and radio button going down and it automatically trigger `mouseout` event. that the issue i guess.

Comment: I changhed div's order and now it works fine. But there is another issue - now, picture shows only on hover, but dissapear when radiobutton is selected. But it must be shown(

Comment: Please share the updated fiddle , it depends on various case like its already selected before hover or after hover you are try to select or after selecting you are moving out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function handlerInFunc(){
    $(".myPicOneClass").show();
}

function handlerOutFunc(){
    $(".myPicOneClass").hide();
}

$(".myRadioOneClass").hover( handlerInFunc, handlerOutFunc );
```

Of course, give the proper class selector names you desire for the specific elements.

Comment: Thank you! It works, but there is another issue - now, picture shows only on hover, but dissapear when radiobutton is selected. But when radiobutton is selected picture and text must be shown(

Comment: Define a CSS class `alwaysShown`. Then you can add an event listener to the radios. When you detect it's selected, then addClass("alwaysShown") to the desired image. But then as you can imagine, what if I select radio 1 and then try to hover over radio 2? I think you are planning inflexible usabilities - Perhaps you can redesign what you want.